# What does the first argument to MySQL's Decimal function do?

Tags: mysql, decimal

Using MySQL 5.0.27

This query:
SELECT CAST('543.21' AS DECIMAL(100,2))

returns 543.21

So does this one:
SELECT CAST('543.21' AS DECIMAL(2,2))

In fact, I am having trouble figuring out what effect the parameter has. I am using it to aggregate numeric values in a varchar column (for legacy reasons!!) and round off to 2 decimal places.

Should I just pick a high number?

Comment: You sure about that? I just ran the second query and it returns .99. What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: That's a rather surprising result! Using 5.0.27, but anyway solved now, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It describes how many total digits a field (or variable) will be able to store.
DECIMAL(100,2) - 100 total digits, 98 before, 2 after a decimal separator
DECIMAL(2,2) 2 total digits, 0 before, 2 after a decimal separator

Explained here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

[added]

For rounding just use ROUND() function.

Comment: Then why doesn't `SELECT CAST('543.21' AS DECIMAL(2,2))` return `.21` ?

Comment: It does return 0.99 for me. Which MySQL version you have?
It seems there were some changes in this area between 5.0 and 5.1
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

Comment: You'd think it should throw an error like SQL Server does (Arithmetic overflow). (Just my $0.02.)

Comment: @Cory Larson: Depending on SQL mode setting it might actually do (did not test).

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.

I was in fact trying to effectively cast and round at the same time using CAST(val AS DECIMAL) but it seems the ROUND() function does an implicit type conversion.

Comment: A change was committed to the MySQL 5.0 tree that handles overflows by returning the highest number that still fits within the bounds of the decimal scale and precision specified. The 0.99 you see is because of that functionality, but it should still show you a warning "Out of range value adjusted for column '...' at row x."

Comment: It does show the warning. I just usually don't pay much attention to them ;)